# Rails: How to inspect a response created with 'render json:'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, controller

I am trying to understand the mechanics of asynchronously updating Rails views by rendering JSON (as my boss wants it done that way).

Not very successful so far.

Is there a way to inspect the response as it is seen on the OS layer? Like when I use `curl`? I am trying to write up my learnings for a possible blog post about this topic and having a way to visualize what Rails sends out when rendering JSON would be really helpful.

The important controller part, looks like this:

```
def create
  @order = Order.find_by(id: params[:order_id])
  @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
  .
  .
  return unless @comment.save!

  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @comment, context: self }
  end

end
```

EDIT:

Based on one of the comments I tried inspecting the response with the debugger/pry, first making sure the @comment object contains data:

```
(byebug) @comment
#<Comment id: 3090, order_id: 125, user_id: 18, content: "asdfad", created_at: "2017-02-01 12:21:25", updated_at: "2017-02-01 12:21:25">
```

Seems good.

```
(byebug) response.body
""
```

Not so cool, where is the JSON data? Why is the body empty?

Comment: Tried any rest clients?

Comment: What does it mean "OS layer"? You can debug your code with [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) or any network analyzer like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

Comment: @sebin: I wouldn't know what rest clients are in this context.

Comment: @Gennady: I called pry in the respond_to block and it actually worked. 'response' is defined in this context. Thx. I didn't expect it to be available there. With OS Layer I meant, displaying the response not as a ruby object but in the same way i can inspect/see responses and requests when working with node.js. This might be confusing as I am still confused in this topic.

Comment: Rest clients are used to make http requests. So you can make a request to your rails application and see the json response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach described above using a spec is totally valid and good. Also you then already have specs in place :)

Anyway one may face some other valid use-cases (there maybe more than the once below) where one needs to inspect requests / responses.

**1. perform some request with javascript to a local / current application**

One can use e.g. the chrome web dev tools to inspect the request, response and headers. This is very useful and handy.

Also you can tail your application log and see the incoming request with params. In rails development you will also see a lot of rails debug information such as active record statements, render calls, mailer interaction and so on.

In addition to the information provided you can add as much debug output (assuming you are in rails development mode) with

```
logger.debug "any important information you need"
```

or even debug with breakpoints [1].

**2. perform some request with javascript to a remote / other application**

In case you have control over the remote application then this is basically them as 1. You just tail the log of the other application. :)

**3. perform a request from within a rails controller to another application**

In case you have control over the other application you can again tail its log, debug with breakpoints or add log output (e.g. from the `@request` variable which is available in controller level)

Also you can use debug logging in the main application and output the response received or debug right in that spot.

If your are using some http client as faraday [2] (which I can highly recommend) you can active its logging. See the basic use chapter [3]. With faraday you can even provide your own logger or use some 3rd party logger [4] to get nicer outputs.

[1] http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

[2] https://github.com/lostisland/faraday

[3] https://github.com/lostisland/faraday#basic-use

[4] https://github.com/envylabs/faraday-detailed_logger

Answer (score 5):

You can write a test to achieve your goal or you can put the code `after_action {puts response.body }` to a controller.

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...
  after_action { puts response.body }
  ...
end
```

**some_test_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe YourController, type: :controller do

  describe "GET #index" do

    it "returns some data" do
      get :index

      puts response.body

      binding.pry # for interactive debugging

      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

  end

end
```